# Chrome 61 body doesn't scroll

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll

Does anyone know why assigning `scrollTop` on the body element no longer works?

eg:
`document.body.scrollTop = 200`

causes the document not to scroll.

**Cause**: Chrome [finally made scrolling spec conformant](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=157855) in version 61

**Solution**: Use [scrollingElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement)

Update the example to:

```
var scrollNode = document.scrollingElement ? 
                 document.scrollingElement : document.body;
scrollNode.scrollTop = 200;
```

Comment: Is this a question? Looks more like an answer

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting a self-answered question. Please rewrite as a question and answer it yourself.

Comment: Yup it is a self answered question as we anticipate some javascript authors to encounter this and we wanted the guidance clear on the sites that they frequently look for answers on. I've changed it more to a question format.

Comment: Hi, Dave, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question and answer look great, but could you please post your solution as a separate answer, not within the question? See ["Can I answer my own question?"](/help/self-answer) in the help center for more details. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewT. I rolled that back, so the information is at least there until someone has a moment to put it in a proper answer (this is getting mentioned in chat bug reports and other places so getting a bit of attention)

Comment: Wait. So wont this break auto scrolling on any sites in loaded in Chrome 61 that is not using scrollingElement -- as in pretty much any site built in the past 5-10 years?

Comment: @Korgrue yes it most likely will. Devastating change. Hooray to the arrogant developers of Chromium.

Comment: Hi @realseanp to me and others (see comments) adding the answer inside the question is quite confusing and since OP can [self answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314165/) i really see no reason or advantage including the answer inside the question. Why did you choose to re-include the answer inside the question?

Comment: While OP can answer his own question you copied context from the original post into someone else's answer - completely changing both the original post and the answer. The problem I see is that the person who wrote the answer had not included anything relating to what you put in the answer. Had that answer been upvoted or selected as the answer it would've given that person credit or an answer they didn't write. Also it seems that that answer has now been deleted. If I had left your edits the knowledge from the original post would've been lost. @surfmuggle

Comment: The solution here doesn't appear to be ideal, and lacks explanation so it doesn't really fit as answer without further research. /cc @surfmuggle

Comment: Why all the commotion about putting the answer in the question!? I wholeheartedly disagree with this notion.

Lacks explanation? How? Op linked directly to the explanation.

Sometimes the people on StackOverflow just grind my gears!

Answer (score 16):

The solution described at the end of this question (checking for `document.scrollingElement` or falling back to `document.body`) won't work on IE, as it doesn't support `document.scrollingElement` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/scrollingElement#Browser_compatibility)), and in IE, the scroll element is the HTML element.

I'd therefore suggest that a better solution for this would be something like;

```
var scrollNode = document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement;
```

Which should work for all modern browsers.

---

As a sidenote, it's interesting to consider that the `scrollingElement` property seems to have been added for the sole purpose of making it so that we *don't* need checks/fallbacks for getting the root scrolling element, but due to more browser incompatibilities, we still need a check/fallback in order to use `scrollingElement`.

Isn't web dev fun?

Comment: I still have a scenario where `document.scrollingElement` is the documentElement but the documentElement is taking up the entire scrollheight, and there is no element in the DOM that actually has the scrollbar (it's like it's on the window).

Answer (score -1):

Ended adding this code to the document ready and it works.
also, i had problems with some tooltips that were misplaced and this code fixed it:

```
    window.onload = function () {
        var GetDocumentScrollTop = function () {
            var isScrollBodyIE = ASPx.Browser.IE && ASPx.GetCurrentStyle(document.body).overflow == "hidden" && document.body.scrollTop > 0;
            if (ASPx.Browser.WebKitFamily || isScrollBodyIE) {
                if (ASPx.Browser.MacOSMobilePlatform)
                    return window.pageYOffset;
                else if (ASPx.Browser.WebKitFamily)
                    return document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
                return document.body.scrollTop;
            }
            else
                return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        };
        var _aspxGetDocumentScrollTop = function () {
            if (__aspxWebKitFamily) {
                if (__aspxMacOSMobilePlatform)
                    return window.pageYOffset;
                else
                    return document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
            }
            else
                return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        if (window._aspxGetDocumentScrollTop) {
            window._aspxGetDocumentScrollTop = _aspxGetDocumentScrollTop;
            window.ASPxClientUtils.GetDocumentScrollTop = _aspxGetDocumentScrollTop;
        } else {
            window.ASPx.GetDocumentScrollTop = GetDocumentScrollTop;
            window.ASPxClientUtils.GetDocumentScrollTop = GetDocumentScrollTop;
        }
    };
```

Hope this could help you.